# Chrome with "ghost" profile

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I have chrome installed with 4 users (Guest, U1, U2, U3)
Now my folder `c:\user\my-user\appdata\Local\google\chrome\userdata` conmtains Profile1/2/3/Default and GuestProfile.

My issue is that I'm running low on space and need to delete some stuff.

I went, through chrome settings, in each profile and deleted the cache. But what I found out is that there is no matching profile folder from `chrome://version/` to "profile 3" that is the one taking the most space on my drive.

Now, how can I find out to what that folder belongs? (I'd like to delete it but I wouldn't like to loose my data, being the biggest I assume it should be linked to my account )

[image]

Comment: You would gain more disk-space by doing [Disk Cleanup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3012-open-use-disk-cleanup-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1):

**"Normal" Method**
Clear all profile cache from Chrome menu: go to a menu like "Other Tools" and "Clear Navigation Data", now select what you want clear.

**Note that if this doesn't work or you are not able to clear in this way, you can also try to clear all profile cache manually**
go to your profile folder, then go to "Cache", press Ctrl + A to select all files, press Shift + Canc to delete all your files and press enter.

Comment: Grazie ma attento ... se non fossi stato Italiano Maiusc non avrei saputo cos'è.
Thanks but... be carefull... if I was,'t italian I wouldn't have understood what Maiusc is (perhaps Shift or Upper)

Anyway no, cannot delete from chrome settings because it seems it have no bindings with that folder. I'll try deleting it all.

Comment: Oops, sorry... I'll change "Maiusc" to "Shift"...